# Why I'm Getting wrong values with Colour detection (OpenCV)

Tags: android, opencv

I have a problem with conversion from BGR to HSV.
I'm programming with Android Studio and testing with my Xperia Z5.

In my code snippet, I'm getting totally wrong colour values:

```
Scalar LOWER_RED  = (0,0,0);
Scalar HIGHER_RED = (30,255,255);

Mat src = new Mat(Bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);
Mat hsv = new Mat(Bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);

Utils bitmapToMat(Bitmap, src);

Imgproc.cvtColor(src,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Core.inRange(hsv, LOWER_RED, HIGHER_RED, hsv);

Utils.matToBitmap(hsv,Bitmap);
```

I want to capture red colour. What did I do wrong?

Edit: 
I tried with all advices and my Code Snippet looks now this way:

```
Scalar LOWER_RED  = (0,10,100);
Scalar HIGHER_RED = (10,255,255);

Mat src = new Mat(Bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
Mat hsv = new Mat(Bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC3);

Utils bitmapToMat(Bitmap, src);

Imgproc.cvtColor(src,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Core.inRange(hsv, LOWER_RED, HIGHER_RED, hsv);

Utils.matToBitmap(hsv,Bitmap);
```

The Outcome is a black screen ( no matches )

with

```
Core.inRange(hsv,New Scalar(0,0,0),New Scalar(10,255,255),HighRedRange);
Core.inRange(hsv,New Scalar(160,100,100),New Scalar(179,255,255),LowRedRange);
Core.addWeighted(LowRedRange,1.0,HighredRange,1.0,0.0,hsv);
```

The vegetables are black and the white background is white in hsv 
[0,0,0 - 10,255,255 AND 160,100,100 - 179,255,255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIanm.png)

If I use a Scalar from 110,100,100 until 135,255,255, then the red pepper is white and the back ground black ( correctly detected ).

Source Picture:

[image]

And I dont understand all this...

Comment: Can you post a sample output?

Comment: "Conversion from BGR to RGB" -- That's not what `COLOR_BGR2HSV` says. | Furthermore, BGR, RGB, HSV... those are all 3 channel images, yet for some obscure reason you create them as `CV_8UC4` (i.e. 4 channel).

Comment: thx for your answers. BGR2RGB was my hasted writing... The correct conversion is like you said BGR2HSV in my question ( corrected ). About C4, i read that HSV is 3 Channel, RGB 4 Channel and greyscaling 1 Channel

Comment: @P.Oni RGB = Red, Green, Blue. That's 3 channels. A 4 channel image could be something like RGBA or similar -- the fourth channel being alpha transparency.

Comment: Appreciated your description!

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/). It's for C++ but the general idea is the same. I tried the general idea and it surely works. The problem is that your range is too broad. In OpenCV, Hue range is in 0-180. Meaning that your higher limit goes to 30*2 = 60 which includes nearly all yellow range too.

I set the range from 0 to 10 for Hue, but remember you may also want to get 160 - 179 range which also includes some part of red. For this, you just need a second mask and then combine them with simple addition.

The example code in Python:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('peppers.jpg',1)

im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

thresh_low = np.array([0,100,100])
thresh_high = np.array([10,255,255]) 

mask = cv2.inRange(im_hsv, thresh_low, thresh_high)

im_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('Masked',im_masked)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know now my problem 
it's this:

Imgproc.cvtColor(src,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

With RGB2HSV all values are correct.
I thought on Android Smartphones there is BGR used ?

However, Big thanks for all answers.

I wish all of you a great day :)

Comment: oh nice to know that thank you for sharing your answer.